# Download a file, the name is not known

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an API for downloading excel file. The API URL is `http://domain.com/export`. The name of this file is not predictable. Also, I need to pass few parameters while calling the API URL.

What is the best way to download a file (JS, jQuery)?

*The solution has to support IE 9+.*

For a test, I have developed one hidden form and jQuery submit. It works, but in the end, I need to put the `download` button to every row in a table and export data related to the row. So maybe it is not the best solution.

My demo solution:

**HTML**

```
 <form id="tool-export" method="post" action="export/">{% csrf_token %}
    <a id="export-link" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">DOWNLOAD</a>
  </form>
```

**JS**

```
  $('#export-link').click(function(e) {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this);
    var form = link.closest('form');

    var project_id = proj_id.find(":selected").val();
    var input = $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'project_id').val(project_id);
    form.append($(input));

    var project_type = proj_type.val();
    input = $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'project_type').val(project_type);
    form.append($(input));

    form.submit();
  });
```

Comment: Just one question , why not  use ajax for posting ?

Comment: So what is the problem? Click the click to all the links/buttons, locate the id in that row.

Comment: @noitse maybe because it is a file download?

Comment: @epascarello hmm , didnt know js security would forbid that.

Comment: @epascarello agree, actually I put this hidden form in each row and it works. I thought maybe there is a better way, without form etc. That's why I asked.

Comment: @trex You can just put one form on the page and select it and set the inputs. You do not need a form in every row.